# Do in-universe characters look down on Hufflepuff?

Tags: harry-potter

Out of universe, some people think that Hufflepuff is "bad", in a condescending sort of way.  Is there anything that parallels this in the books?  Do the other wizards frown down upon Hufflepuffs and think that "getting sorted into Hufflepuff is a pat on the head and a kindly expectation that you'll never accomplish much"?

This question was based on [another question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/11435/are-there-any-important-extraordinary-or-accomplished-hufflepuffs), which seemed somewhat disdainful towards the Hufflepuffs.

Comment: *Wizard People, Dear Reader* refers to Hufflepuff as "the remedial class," but it also refers to it as "Hufferpuffer," so maybe it's not a reliable source.

Comment: Noting that the title of this question has changed from "Is being in Hufflepuff bad?", the answer is, of course, No. Some inherently bad people are Sorted to Hufflepuff; Hufflepuff does not turn a person. Inherently bad people have been Sorted to *all* of the four houses and JKR has been up front about this. The attributes outlined in the first (older) question establish that being in Hufflepuff is not bad. I feel this is a duplicate question accordingly. But there is no point in a hammer war.

Comment: [The Helping Hands for Hufflepuffs Foundation](https://youtu.be/9D1_PqADgOg?t=8m15s) made a video raising awareness for the poor wizards afflicted with being sorted into Hufflepuff :-)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

**There are certainly some people who look down on Hufflepuff.**

Examples:

- When Draco introduces himself to Harry in *Philosopher’s Stone*, he says:

  > “Well, no one really knows until they get there, do they, but I know I’ll be in Slytherin, all our family have been – **imagine being in Hufflepuff, I think I’d leave, wouldn’t you**?”
- Later, when Hagrid explains the house system to Harry, he mentions this notion (although it's not entirely clear whether Hagrid is just repeating the meme, or actually agrees with it):

  > “And what are Slytherin and Hufflepuff?”
  >
  > “School houses. There’s four. **Everyone says Hufflepuff are a lot o’ duffers**, but –”
- In the Pottermore welcome letter for Hufflepuff, the Prefect acknowledges a general sentiment that Hufflepuff is unimpressive:

  > There are a few things you should know about Hufflepuff house. First of all, let’s deal with **a perennial myth about the place, which is that we’re the least clever house**. […] We’ve produced more than our fair share of powerful, brilliant and daring witches and wizards, but, just because we don’t shout about it, we don’t get the credit we deserve.
- This is a bit different, but when Harry is chosen as a Triwizard Champion alongside Cedric, it’s repeated that Hufflepuff doesn’t have a great reputation:

  > It was plain that the Hufflepuffs felt that Harry had stolen their champion’s glory; a feeling exacerbated, perhaps, by the fact that **Hufflepuff House very rarely got any glory**, and that Cedric was one of the few who had ever given them any, having beaten Gryffindor once at Quidditch.

Answer (score 29):

**Malfoy** was derisive of Hufflepuff House before he even arrived at Hogwarts:

> "Well, no one really knows until they get there, do they, but I know I'll be in Slytherin, all our family have been — imagine being in Hufflepuff, I think I'd leave, wouldn't you?"
> <sub>-- Draco Malfoy, *HP and the Philosopher's Stone*</sub>

But then he's never been known for his acceptance of non-Slytherins in any case.

The Sorting Hat's song (or one of them) suggests Hufflepuff is the house for **leftovers**, those who aren't considered 'good enough' (by various definitions of 'good') to fit into any other:

> Said Slytherin, "We'll teach just those whose ancestry's purest."
> Said Ravenclaw, "We'll teach those whose intelligence is surest"
> Said Gryffindor, "We'll teach all those with brave deeds to their name."
> Said Hufflepuff, "I'll teach the lot and treat them just the same."
>
> [...]
>
> For instance, Slytherin took only pure-blood wizards of great cunning just like him.
> And only those of sharpest mind were taught by Ravenclaw
> While the bravest and the boldest went to daring Gryffindor.
> Good Hufflepuff, she took the rest and taught them all she knew,
> <sub>-- Sorting Hat, *HP and the Order of the Phoenix*</sub>

There's also a line to suggest Hufflepuff is generally underappreciated:

> Cedric was walking away from the sort of glory Hufflepuff hadn't had in centuries.
> <sub>-- *HP and the Goblet of Fire* (when Cedric Diggory offers to let Harry take the Triwizard Cup)</sub>

However, it should be noted that **J K Rowling does *not* believe Hufflepuff is bad**:

> "This may surprise people, but it is the truth...In many, many ways, Hufflepuff is my favourite House. Here's my reasoning, bear with me. [...] The Hufflepuffs stayed for a different reason; they weren't trying to show off, they weren't being reckless, that's the essence of Hufflepuff House. Now my oldest child [...] said to me —and she, by the way, was not sorted into Hufflepuff House— but, she said to me, 'I think we should all want to be Hufflepuffs.' I can only say to you, that I would not be at all disappointed to be sorted into Hufflepuff House."
> <sub>-- J K Rowling, [web interview *Beyond the Page*](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Harry_Potter:_Beyond_the_Page)</sub>

Comment: Maybe JKR loves them, but she certainly did not write much interesting about them...

Comment: Agreed, Hufflepuffs do little in the books.